# Filter out html tag and replace with other html tags using sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I was replacing `<B>` and `</B>` with `<STRONG>` and `</STRONG>` in a file. It's somewhat like replacing hmtl tags. I used `sed 's/\<B\>/STRONG/g'`. It did the job but if in file `[B]` and `[/B]` is present. Then also they are changed into `[STRONG]` and `[/STRONG]`. I don't get the logic behind it.

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @abligh That doesn't really make sense in this context; the OP is not even parsing anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, sed uses basic regular expressions.  That means that GNU lets `\<` match the beginning of a word and `\>` match the end of a word.  Observe:

```
$ echo '<B> BBB B' | sed 's/\<B\>/STRONG/g'
<STRONG> BBB STRONG
```

`\<B\>` matches the word `B` which appears twice in the above string.  Because it matches the word `B` and not the angle brackets, the angle brackets are left unchanged.

If you want to match angle brackets, `<>`, leave the backslash off:

```
$ echo '<B> BBB B' | sed 's/<B>/<STRONG>/g'
<STRONG> BBB B
```

`<B>` matches open angle bracket followed by `B` followed by closing angle bracket.  Thus, `<B>` is replaced with `<STRONG>` but `B` is left alone.

#### Catching both the open and closing tags

```
$ echo '<B> BBB B </B>' | sed -r 's|<(/)?B>|<\1STRONG>|g'
<STRONG> BBB B </STRONG>
```

`-r` is for extended regex but recent versions of GNU sed also support `-E` as a synonym for `-r`.  BSD sed uses `-E` for this and, reportedly, future POSIX standards have adopted `-E`.  Thus, for compatibility, one may want to use (hat tip @Kos):

```
$ echo '<B> BBB B </B>' | sed -E 's|<(/)?B>|<\1STRONG>|g'
<STRONG> BBB B </STRONG>
```

Comment: It's ok, but it misses closing tags (e.g. `</B>` will be left untouched)

Comment: @kos OK.  I added a solution to catch that also.

Comment: Ok, last suggestion, maybe use `-E` instead of `-r`: it's POSIX (e.g. it will make the command work also on say BSD `sed`) and it should soon replace `-r`, which will be instead depreacted exactly for its non-POSIX compliance

Comment: @kos  I know that some versions of GNU sed have supported `-E` as an undocumented synonym for `-r` but I didn't know that it had become POSIX.  Where did you see that?  I just checked [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and didn't see `-E` listed.

Comment: Apologies, it's not standardized yet; I missunderstood  [Stéphane Chazelas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas)'s comment to an answer of mine, but it looks like it's scheduled to be so: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211622/using-sed-to-replace-a-string-with-the-last-character-unspecified/211623#comment358450_211623

Comment: @kos Interesting.  It will be nice to have one less BSD/GNU incompatibility.

Comment: I agree: also (just to exhaust all the `-E` usage claims / facts) it should be also noted that `-E` it's the standard yet in `grep`, so maybe `-E` would be preferable also for this resemblance (not to push you to do so of course, `-r` it's fine, just to explain my previous reasoning).

Comment: @kos I updated the answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

`<` and `>` aren't special characters in [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), so they shouldn't be escaped. When you escaped them, `sed` will try to treat them as special characters, and then the behaviour is [undefined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_02):

> The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by a 
>   ( '\' ) is undefined, except for:
>
> - The characters ')', '(', '{', and '}'
> - The digits 1 to 9 inclusive (see [BREs Matching Multiple Characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06))
> - A character inside a bracket expression

So, just use `<` and `>` without escaping:

```
$ echo 'b<b>' | sed 's/<b>/strong/'  
bstrong
```

Comment: can u please explain the behaviour which i asked in the question

Comment: @user2280915 when the standards say something is  [**undefined**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), anything may happen. In this case, `sed` likely ignores escaped characters which don't have any speciality.

Comment: @user2280915 probably all the `B`s must have replaced by `STRONG` in your case.

Comment: @Ron Yes. U pointed out correctly. I just tried. It replaces all single Bs ie B with spaces at both end. [space]B[space].

Comment: It is true that `\<` is undefined for POSIX sed but [a GNU sed extension](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) makes `\<` an active character.

Comment: This will replace every `<b>` tag with `strong`, but this will actually break the markup; it should be `<strong>`, and possible closing tags should be taken care of (e.g. `</b>` should become `</strong>`)

Comment: @kos OP can fix that on their own.

Comment: @John1024 indeed.

Comment: @Ron I don't think so, if the `<B></B>` tags contain a string such as "Bolded text" that would break the string.

Comment: @kos You're right, I should have said all the 'single' `B`s

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `awk`. Here I have a sample file with two lines that contain  **and**  tags and use `gsub` function to replace them. Then we output that to temp file and back into original file. Remove temp file when done. Adapt as necessary.

```
$ cat tags.txt                                                                                                                                      
<B> and </B>
<B> or </B>

$ awk '{gsub("<B>","<STRONG>"); gsub("</B>","</STRONG>");print}' tags.txt                                                                           
<STRONG> and </STRONG>
<STRONG> or </STRONG>

$ awk '{gsub("<B>","<STRONG>"); gsub("</B>","</STRONG>");print}' tags.txt > tmpfile.txt && cat tmpfile > tags.txt
```

Comment: +1 but I can't look at that `&& cat tmpfile > tags.txt`! ;) Maybe use a clever command substitution like `<<< "$(< tags.txt)" awk '{gsub("<B>","<STRONG>"); gsub("</B>","</STRONG>");print}' > tags.txt` or something like `sponge`: `awk '{gsub("<B>","<STRONG>"); gsub("</B>","</STRONG>");print}' tags.txt | sponge tags.txt`

Comment: @kos What do you mean " I can't look  at that  . . . " ? you mean the line is too long or is it just awkward  to use > redirection ?

Comment: @kos GNU awk supports in-place editing (`-i inplace`).

Comment: Yes, it looks a bit ugly, however the best solution would be to use `gawk` instead of `awk` as muru mentioned

Comment: @muru I'm not on Ubuntu right now, but if I recall `gawk` is not installed by default, I think that's why Serg didn't want to use it

Comment: @muru that's why I've used the redirection instead of `-i`. It's not a fact OP has gawk. I think by default ubuntu comes with mawk, if I'm not mistaken. Hence there's no in-place editing